# How to configure nginx for Amazon ec2

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, uwsgi

I saw example configurations of `nginx`, most of them use example.com as a `server_name` and `uwsgi_pass` similar to `unix:/var/www/run/blog.sock;` or in combination with ip/port address. but what should I use in case of amazon ec2 instance, since it has long public name, ip is private and if I restart my instance it gets different public name and ip. I need shutdown instances sometime. I want to configure it for using uwsgi+django, but I am totally beginner in web area and servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `server_name` directive is useful in cases where you want to host different sites on the same server, and handling them differently depending on the "Host" header field (ex: mysite1.com => a PHP website, mysite2.com => a django website,...)
It's actually a virtual server (see also [the server directive])[1](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server).

From [this article](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) :

> [...] nginx tests only the request’s header field 
>   “Host” [against the server_name directive] to determine which server the request should be routed to. If
>   its value does not match any server name, or the request does not
>   contain this header field at all, then nginx will route the request to
>   the default server for this port.

If I understood, you don't want that. So you can use the [underscore character](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#miscellaneous_names) (in the **Miscellaneous Names** section).

When I don't need to handle specific domains, I generally use "localhost". To be honest I couldn't find any explanation on what it does. I just found examples with this value, and it seems to work exactly as the underscore character.

So I'd go with

```
server_name _;
```

or

```
server_name localhost;
```